# Why does this GIF end up as a black square when resizing with Java ImageIO

Tags: java, resize, gif, javax.imageio

Java ImageIO correctly displays this black & white image http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/black.gif but when I try and resize it using this code

```
public static BufferedImage resize2D(Image srcImage, int size)
{
    int w = srcImage.getWidth(null);
    int h = srcImage.getHeight(null);

    // Determine the scaling required to get desired result.
    float scaleW = (float) size / (float) w;
    float scaleH = (float) size / (float) h;

    MainWindow.logger.finest("Image Resizing to size:" + size + " w:" + w + ":h:" + h + ":scaleW:" + scaleW + ":scaleH" + scaleH);

    //Create an image buffer in which to paint on, create as an opaque Rgb type image, it doesn't matter what type
    //the original image is we want to convert to the best type for displaying on screen regardless
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Set the scale.
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.scale(scaleW, scaleH);

    // Paint image.
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
                    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g2d.drawImage(srcImage, tx, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

I just end up with a black image. Im trying to make the image smaller (a thumbnail) but even if I resize it larger for test purposes it still ends up as a black square.

Other images resize okay, anyone know what is the problem with the gif/and or Java Bug

Comment: Does it behave different if part of the images are transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the string representation of the `ColorModel` of the linked image when loaded through `ImageIO`:

```
IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 1 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@1572e449 transparency = 2 transIndex   = 1 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false
```

If I understand this correctly, you have one bit per pixel, where a `0` bit is opaque black and a `1` bit is transparent.  Your `BufferedImage` is initially all black, so drawing a mixture of black and transparent pixels onto it will have no effect.

Although you are using `AlphaComposite.Src` this will not help as the R/G/B values for the transparent palette entry read as zero (I am not sure whether this is encoded in the GIF or just the default in the JDK.)

You can work around it by:

1. Initializing the `BufferedImage` with all-white pixels
2. Using `AlphaComposite.SrcOver`

So the last part of your `resize2D` implementation would become:

```
// Paint image.
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
g2d.drawImage(srcImage, tx, null);
```

Comment: thats works, thankyou ! So it just begs one question would there be any reason not to  add your fix to my resize routine so that is it used for all images(gif,png,jpeg..) , including all those that are currently displaying fine.

Comment: @user294896: Maybe.  If two source images are partially transparent but one is designed to be painted over a black background and another over a white background then whatever background color you choose, one of them will look wrong.

Comment: right well they are rarely transparent at all so should be okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

That makes it work.  Of course, the question is why..?

Comment: really? still doesn't work for me. It works if you save in a different format e.g. "png". I think it may have to do with transparency in gifs.

Comment: doesnt work for me either, to clarify I display the resultant  image within a JLabel as an ImageIcon

Comment: Huh.  Yeah, I'm using a JLabel too in my test code and it scales up and down just fine with that single change.  So, maybe there's also a JVM bug.  I'm using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode) on MacOS 10.6.5.

Comment: maybe it just fixed in the mac version because Ive tried using 1.6.0_22 and 1.6.0_23 on Windows 7